# How to access Eigen Vector Matrix< float, 2, 1 >

Tags: c++, eigen

I am iterating through a vector, which consists of Vector

```
Matrix<float, 2, 1>

for(auto it = uvVertices.begin(); it != uvVertices.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it;  
}
```

this gives an output like: which works

0.123120.212354

which is correct, how can i access only the first or the second component? So that i get

0.12312

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html here is  a reference but i could not figur eit out.

Comment: Can you please show what `uvVertices` is exactly, so we know what do you actually mean, and expect? Or some example what is your input and desired output?

Comment: uvVertices is a vector of ''Vector Matrix<float, 2, 1>''

Comment: No, there is no such thing. It wouldn't compile. You should have provided the real declaration you used in code. But it doesn't matter now.

Comment: ok it's actually a typedef to Vector2f. Does this satisfy the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly... You can just dereference the iterator to a temporary reference inside the loop for convenience and access coefficients inside like with any `Eigen` object:

```
for(auto it = uvVertices.begin(); it != uvVertices.end(); ++it) {
    Matrix<float, 2, 1>& v = *it;
    //auto& v = *it; // should also work
    std::cout << v(0,0);  
    std::cout << v(1,0);
}
```

You could also use range-for:

```
for(auto& v  : uvVertices) {
    std::cout << v(0,0);  
    std::cout << v(1,0);
}
```

I would also consider using `Eigen::Vector` type for a vector.

Comment: in the first code snippet what is the & for? is this an operator? Or a reference?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to get the `n`-th element of a container, you can use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), like this:

```
auto pos = 1; // Get the second element
auto it(std::next(uvVertices.begin(), k));
std::cout << *it;
```

The initial element can be accessed simply by dereferencing `uvVertices.begin()`, like this:

```
std::cout << *(uvVertices.begin()); // Get the initial element
```

Comment: Does `next` change the input iterator? The doc looks more like it returns a new one that is advanced n steps.

Comment: @Slauma You're right, I mixed up `std::next` and `std::advance`

Comment: var count = 0 is this c++?

Comment: @user1767754 Darn, I did it again! That's what happens when you program in a single language for too long. Of course `var` isn't C++, it's C#. This is fixed now.

Comment: I don't think OP means what you think he does. He doesn't want to iterate only on two elements of a vector. He has a `vector< Matrix<float, 2, 1> >` and wants to access only one coefficient. But he gets both, because Eigen defines `operator<<(ostream, Eigen::Matrix)` or whatever is needed to work with `ostream`s. So he dereferences iterator to a Matrix, and fires up the overloaded operator for whole Matrix, not just one coefficient. But it's quite a guess TBH.

Comment: @luk32 You're right, he said "only the first *or* the second component" which I for some reason misread as "only the first *and* the second component". Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Well I am not absolutely sure if I am totally right either. If Eigen defines `begin()` and `end()` then you could interface it like that, but I think your code still doesn't solve the problem =). You need to dereference the iterator, and then access the needed coeff. But it was poorly worded IMO. I figured it out 'cause I work with Eigen and knew it has overloads for `operator<<` so I understood OP better. `vector` was `std::vector` and `Vector` was `Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 1>`.